# How to manage Multiple single page through single.php?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

There is `Post` that have certain data could be viewed in `blog` nav-menu that is using `index.php` and for the single post it retrieves data from `single.php`. I also have another custom post type that is `client` could be viewed from `Our- client` nav menu and it is using `client template`. Now the problem is i also want a custom single page for single client so i am using `single-client.php` but when i click to any client it leads to `single.php` not single-client. php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `single.php` and both post types will use it, as long as you remove the other two files from your theme.

Then you could fetch different template parts depending on the post type being queried.

However you do it, you're going to need separate files with stuff for the two different post types, unless the to are going to have the exact same design.

EDIT

I think I may have misunderstood.

Is your issue that the single posts are not displaying, but you want to keep using the two separate single templates?

In that case, make sure the post types are called `blog` and `client`.

To check, go to each post type's section in the admin panel. On each of these pages check the `post_type` URL parameter in your address bar.

Comment: I am having two separate designs for the blog and client single pages. but my blog information are on post. and my client information are on client post types.

Comment: My single post is displaying but i want another single post for client post types and it is leading to again the single.php not single-client.php